# iWebDriver does not contain definition for Find element: c# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium and I'm working on an automation with c#. I was trying to do a click interaction with a button and I get an error message.
When I hard-code the values for the particular button, I am able to successfully click. But I need to pass a variable to the xPath so that based on the variable, different buttons can be clicked. This is where it gets tricky.

The below code is the hard-coded one and it works fine

```
var divButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id=\"catalogItems\"]/li[4]/div/div[2]"));
var button = divButton.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id=\"add_e101213_100663\"]"));

//Below is the one where i try to pass a variable:

string xPathVariable = xcelRange.Cells[9][i].value2;
string xPathVariable2 = xcelRange.Cells[8][i].value2;
var divButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xPathVariable));
var button = divButton.FindElement(By.XPath(xPathVariable2));

//The values in excel are catalogItems\"]/li[4]/div/div[2] and add_e101213_100663
```

I tried saving the same xpath in excel sheet and tried to pass it and it wont work.

I get an error saying the iWebdrive does not have a definition for findelement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the HTML and also the code where you are initialising the driver. And also the error message

Comment: Can you try xcelRange.Cells[8][i].value2.ToString();

Comment: @jinglyhk,  can you try providing the entire xpath like **".//*[@id=\"catalogItems\"]/li[4]/div/div[2]"** in the excel sheet, also can you print it in the console and check whether you are getting the same.

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan 
I did something like that and it worked. I copied the entire path and pasted them in the excel sheet and then passed those to the code.